# topological space in which compace set is closed

Tags: general-topology

I saw the bellow example in this site that "The product of two $T_B$ spaces need not be $T_B$.

Let $\Bbb Q^*$ be the one-point compactification of the rationals; then $\Bbb Q^*$ is $KC$, but $X=\Bbb Q^*\times\Bbb 
Q^*$ is not. It's well-known that $\Bbb Q^*$ is $T_B$. To see that $X$ is not, let $\Delta=\{\langle x,x\rangle:x\in\Bbb Q^*\}$. Then $\Delta$ is homeomorphic to $\Bbb Q^*$, so $\Delta$ is compact.

Let $p=\langle\infty,0\rangle\in X$. For each $\epsilon>0$ let $I_\epsilon=(-\epsilon,\epsilon)\cap\Bbb Q$. For each compact subset $K$ of $\Bbb Q$ and $\epsilon>0$ let $B(K,\epsilon)=(\Bbb Q^*\setminus K)\times I_\epsilon$, and let $\mathscr{B}$ be the family of all such $B(K,\epsilon)$; $\mathscr{B}$ is a local base at $p$. Fix $B(K,\epsilon)\in\mathscr{B}$.  $I_\epsilon\setminus K\ne\varnothing$, so let $y\in I_\epsilon\setminus K$; then $\langle y,y\rangle\in\Delta\cap B(K,\epsilon)$, and since $B(K,\epsilon)$ was arbitrary, it follows that $p\in(\operatorname{cl}_X\Delta)\setminus\Delta$ and hence that $\Delta$ is not closed.

> I would like to know,
>
> why  is "$I_\epsilon\setminus K\ne\varnothing$"? And $p\in(\operatorname{cl}_X\Delta)\setminus\Delta$?

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\cl}{\operatorname{cl}}$$K$ is a compact set of rational numbers. Suppose that $K\supseteq I_\epsilon$. Let $\delta\in(0,\epsilon)$ be irrational; clearly $K\supseteq I_\delta$. $K$ is closed in $\Bbb Q$, so $K\supseteq\cl_{\Bbb Q}I_\delta$, and $K$ is compact, so $\cl_{\Bbb Q}I_\delta$ is compact. But $\cl_{\Bbb Q}I_\delta=I_\delta=(-\delta,\delta)\cap\Bbb Q$, which is not compact. This contradiction shows that $K\nsupseteq I_\epsilon$ and hence that $I_\epsilon\setminus K\ne\varnothing$.

Clearly $p\notin\Delta$, since $0\ne\infty$, so we need only show that $p\in\cl_X\Delta$. But that’s exactly what I did in the quoted argument: every open nbhd of $p$ contains a member of $\mathscr{B}$, and for each $B(K,\epsilon)\in\mathscr{B}$ I found a point $\langle y,y\rangle\in\Delta\cap B(K,\epsilon)$. Thus, every open nbhd of $p$ intersects $\Delta$, and therefore $p\in\cl_X\Delta$.